# DeprecationWarning when importing Scikit-learn

Tags: python, numpy, scikit-learn, deprecation-warning

I'm using JupyterLab.

When importing some packages, or executing some functions from scikit-learn,
very long list of deprecation warnings fill the screen.

[image]

[image]

[image]
I googled about this problem and upgraded the packages (scikit-learn, numpy), but I still get the warnings.

```
pip install scikit-learn --upgrade
Requirement already satisfied: scikit-learn in c:\users\...\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages (1.0.2)
Requirement already satisfied: threadpoolctl>=2.0.0 in c:\users\...\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages (from scikit-learn) (3.0.0)
Requirement already satisfied: joblib>=0.11 in c:\users\...\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages (from scikit-learn) (1.1.0)
Requirement already satisfied: numpy>=1.14.6 in c:\users\...\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages (from scikit-learn) (1.22.1)
Requirement already satisfied: scipy>=1.1.0 in c:\users\...\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages (from scikit-learn) (1.7.2)
```

Some say that these are not problems because they are just warnings and not harmful.

But it's very annoying. How can I solve this problem?

Comment: I don't use `conda`, but maybe you are? I really don't know but perhaps using `conda update` might work for you?

Comment: @rickhg12hs It worked!!  Thank you :)